# What code it is and how to rewrite in php

Tags: php, .net

i have got this code from one of api provider

Not sure its asp .net or something

Need to convert to php

i tried with some online tools, no luck.

Some One help what code it is and how i can convert to php.

```
            string CrypCode = (DateTime.Now.Year.ToString()+ (Seed + DateTime.Now.DayOfYear.ToString()));
            System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider x = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] bs = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(CrypCode);
            bs = x.ComputeHash(bs);
            System.Text.StringBuilder s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            foreach (byte b in bs)
            {
                s.Append(b.ToString("x2").ToLower());
            }
            string KEY = s.ToString();
            return KEY;
```

Comment: We aren't a coding service. Show us the code you've attempted with so far.

Comment: looks like c# to me

Comment: @delboy1978uk Thanks for your time i tried with online tools you can see it in my question itself

Comment: We need to see what PHP you have tried with

Comment: @delboy1978uk       Even i don't know exactly on what language above code is written in when i refered google i came to know that System.Security can be used in .net Can u can tell what language its written in

Comment: This code basicly creates a random UUID, right? I guess it would be easier to build (=copy and paste) one already written in php than to convert this one.

Comment: what's the input, and what's the expected output?

Comment: Think Jeff's right, looks like c#. Converting it exactly probably won't be possible without the underlying code/knowledge of how it's computing the hash with the `MD5CryptoServiceProvider` and how `x.ComputeHash()` is working.

Comment: _“i have got this code from one of api provider”_ - any API provider worth half their salt should give you a documentation or specification on stuff like this, rather than just throwing a code snippet at you.

Comment: @misorude YOU ARE RIGHT UNFORTUNATELY I DIDN'T GOT ANY DOCUMENT OR SPECIFICATION I TRIED SOMETHING NOW . I CAN  HEARTILY ASK THEM TO PROVIDE

Comment: `MD5CryptoServiceProdiver` is the NET frameworks way of computing md5 hash. In php you can just do it by using `md5()` function

Answer (score 0):

I remember when i used to work with VB.NET. Hashing is headache. I see you are trying to md5 hash crypcode. In php its simple. Dont know why Microsoft languages long it out. They must have their reasons. Believe it or not in php its one line.

```
$crypcode = date("Y") + ($seed + date("z"));
$key = md5($crypcode);
return $key;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.md5cryptoserviceprovider